# Keyboard visibility permanently on screen

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to set so that when I turn on the new screen:

- the keyboard turns on
- the keyboard will always be visible

I have one TextInput on the screen and the option to select from select

I would like the keyboard to be always visible, regardless of whether we have clicked Input or do something else on the screen

On the keyboard there is a button with the function instead of Enter

Comment: If anyone thinks the question is inappropriate, write. Minus without messages is not cultural

Answer (score 1):

Use the `autoFocus` prop on the `TextInput` component and then put keyboardShouldPersistTaps on your Parent View

Comment: Does `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` only work for `ScrollView`? I don't have ScrollView

Comment: Try using ScrollView with scrollEnabled={false} @startNet